# Painel setting in canvas scene

Tags: unity, gui

This is where I am having to place my panel in canvas scene for it goes to the right place when I play it in full mode. Anyone knows how to do it correctly?

**In scene:**
[image: In scene]
**Play mode:**
[image: Play Mode]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want your panel to stay docked against the left side of your screen, and enlarge to fill the vertical height.

To do that, click on the little box on the left side of your `RectTransform` inspector that currently says "Center Middle" - this lets you control the alignment of the object using [Anchor Presets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html).

Clicking it opens a matrix of various options:

[image: Anchor Presets]

You want the one I've highlighted in yellow on the bottom left. That says "Align relative to the left edge of your parent element, and enlarge with your parent element vertically"

Unity will automatically adjust the other parameters in the `RectTransform` to preserve the panel's current appearance under the new preset, but you can modify them to nudge it around or change the amount of margin it leaves.

You can also [constrain your game window to your play mode resolution/aspect](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GameView.html) so that at edit time you're working with the same framing as you'll see during play.

Comment: I will create a new one to see what happens tomorrow because today I tried in this one and nothing changed.

Comment: As I mentioned, Unity will automatically adjust the other parameters to keep the panel in its current position & size. What changes is how it reacts to changes in its parent's size. You can edit the position properties to adjust the panel's location and size relative to its parent's edge.